# <p> Inception - HTML

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

In my HTML project, I am trying to mention the `<p>` tag. However, VS Code is interpreting it as an actual `<p>` tag and it causes weird things to happen. Does anybody have a way to get around this? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `&lt;` in place of `<` and `&gt;` in place of `>`.

Bytheway, it is common to style code snippets with the code tag.

```
<code>&lt;p&gt;</code>
```

And if you ever need a multiline code snippet, wrap it in a pre tag to preserve whitespace.

```
<pre><code>&lt;p&gt;
    this stays indented and the newlines where added without a br tag
&lt;/p&gt;
</code></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use HTML character entities for greater than & less than signs. Try

```
&gt;p&lt;
```

Comment: and for the `&` character

Answer (score 0):

Use them between `<xmp></xmp>` tag.
Code:

```
<xmp><p></p></xmp>
```

Output:

```
<p></p>
```

Comment: This was removed from the language in HTML5 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp, and only works in browsers (for now) for legacy reasons.